# Jackson CSV Writter throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson

I have a weird error, which sometime happens sometime doesn't.

Using the same data with the following version Jackson 1.9.9 with the Jackson CSV Data Formatter 1.9.4 (jackson-dataformat-csv), i get the below error.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) 
at org.codehaus.jackson.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:458) 
at org.codehaus.jackson.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:69) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.CsvWriter._flushBuffer(CsvWriter.java:514) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.CsvWriter.endRow(CsvWriter.java:252) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator.finishRow(CsvGenerator.java:579) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator.close(CsvGenerator.java:277) 
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2584) 
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
```

I also get double comma on some of the columns. My guess is that its a bug within the CsvGenerator.

Comment: Please also provide your source code.

Comment: the source code would is  final CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder().disableEscapeChar().setUseHeader(true).setColumnSeparator(';')
     .addColumn("C1")
     .addColumn("C2")
     .addColumn("C3").build();


   final String writeValueAsString = this.mapper.schemaBasedWriter(schema).writeValueAsString(this.data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug. But one thing to note is that 1.9.x version is not really being developed, so if possible you would want to use version for Jackson 2.x (latest being 2.1.1).

Comment: I tried to upgrade and found that all the standard mappers were missing, when trying to use Jersey and Jackson. if i can remember, i think the jackson jaxrs jar is missing (or i couldn't find it in 2.x and up)

Comment: Not missing, but on its own project -- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -- same applies for some other things like Joda types. And 2.x core, annotations, data-binding work together, separate from 1.x.

Comment: thanks, i was hunting for the providers... it seems the upgrade fixed a whole host of minor problems as well (double comma being one). the Index Error has not appear after a few runs, so it looks to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception by limiting the property names of the pojo to less than 20. And in case you are using any Decimal Formatters in your code, You are likely to get the exception. 1.9.4 is buggy and 2.0 is definately a better version